# Can data in Solr be extended with manually defined meta data?

Tags: search, solr

I have several documents in a solr collection that I want to be able to search through. Most of the data comes from web sites I can easily crawl, however, I need to add some attributes manually to because I have to add these attributes manually.

So as an example I get the following info from a site (all attributes returned from crawled site):

```
 Name: Porsche Boxter
 Year: 1996
 ...
```

I want to add additional fields through a web interface (info not present on crawled sites):

```
 Cool: yes
 foo: bar
```

My questions:

1. Does it make sense at all to store additional information along the indexed data within Solr (inside the documents) or would a best practice only have all crawled data in Solr and merge with an external managed database during query time? To me it makes more sense to have all my data that is eventually queried in Solr as some of the manually added attributed are required search criteria (e.g. look only for cool cars from the 90s).
2. Is it possible to use Solr to store additional information about indexed documents? I know the entire schema in advance, perhaps this is useful?
3. If I store my data exclusively in Solr, how can I ensure that during the next crawl the manually added data is not overwritten? Would partial update be required?

Since I am new to Solr it would also be very helpful if someone could simply manage what to look for in the documentation that describes my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That depends on how often the external data changes. The more often, the less meaningful. Generally it is a good idea to store such data along the index data, because you get them without an additional database query.
2. Yes. Use `indexed:false`and `stored:true`. If you knew not know all of such fields in advance you could use a [dynamicField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) like `<dynamicField name="*_stored" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />`.
3. Yes. You have to use [partial update](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/). This is no problem in your case, because the fields not updated have `stored:true`.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds very helpful indeed.